# How do I edit an android studio Java code to work on a newer version of Gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run a BLE scanner code sourced from github.

Source code: https://github.com/joelwass/Android-BLE-Scan-Example

The issue is that it is a code from 6 years ago and no newer codes have been made to my knowledge. On attempting the run the code it asks for Gradle 2.8 to be installed. When i installed and synced Gradle 2.8 to the app in android studio it gives this error.

Error: **This version of Android Studio requires projects to use Gradle 4.8.1 or newer.**

However, installing anything newer gives the original error about requiring Gradle 2.8. I am in no position nor time frame to try and build a BLE scanner from scratch and would love to get this source code working as a base to my app adjustments.

Is it best to download an older version of android studio, or is it possible to change the applications gradle files, so that it accepts newer versions?

Any help is much appreciated!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the file build.gradle and replace this:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8.1'

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion this didnt work unfortunately Error: **Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8.1.**